# AzureAD authentication and JWT bearer authentication on Graphql

Tags: .net-core, graphql, azure-ad-msal

I have two authentication schemes, one is for the JWT token generated by Ms IdentityServer 4 and the other is for JWT from the Azure AD token. This works for Rest API calls in for services in my micro service environment but there is another service that has graphql running in it.

According to the graphql documentation we are instructed to use the Authorization attribute from the HotChocolates package and not the Dotnet's Authorization.

I have used the following without any luck

```
    //[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer, AAD")]
    //[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = Utlities.Constants.AuthSchemes)]
    //[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = Utlities.Constants.AuthSchemes)]
```

PS: note that I'm using the token that is received from the front end upon AzureAD sign in

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance guys. Drop a comment if any of you need more information